# NameError: name 'vector' is not defined on Segmented project

Tags: pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, google-colab

I want to visualize my geopy Segment Anything Model for Geospatial Data of my neighborhood, but at the visualization stage I got this reply

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-384fdbe53809> in <cell line: 7>()
      5     'fillOpacity': 0.5,
      6 }
----> 7 m.add_vector(vector, layer_name='vector', style=style)
      8 m

NameError: name 'vector' is not defined
```

I want to recreate the result from this [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/opengeos/segment-geospatial/blob/main/docs/examples/satellite.ipynb)
and This is my [Github commit for this project](https://github.com/vellos0x1/Demz1/blob/926f03e896bfb1cb8e0274e575788ede35faa90d/Gading_Kirana.ipynb)